# Change font-awesome icon color when mouse over

Tags: html, css, icons, font-awesome

I have icons inside the input text box. when mouse over the icons I want to 
change the color of icons.and I tried but that won't work.

Below my code.

```
<div class="row">
        <span class="fa fa-envelope" style="position: absolute; top: 10px; left: -5px; color: black"></span>
        <span class="fa fa-file" style="position: absolute; top: 10px; left: 20px; color: black"></span>
        <span class="fa fa-calendar" style="position: absolute; top: 10px; left: 42px; color: black"></span>
        <span class="fa fa-bar-chart" style="position: absolute; top: 10px; left: 65px; color: black"></span>
        <input id="Text1" class="col-md-8" type="text" placeholder="Send Message" style="padding: 30px; border: 1px solid #aaa />
    </div>
```

I need solution for that problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd rather suggest removing the inline `color: black` and replace it with css styles. Avoid using `!important` when you can, right?

```css
.fa{
  color: black
}
.fa:hover{
  color:blue;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
        <span class="fa fa-envelope" style="position: absolute; top: 10px; left: -5px;"></span>
        <span class="fa fa-file" style="position: absolute; top: 10px; left: 20px;"></span>
        <span class="fa fa-calendar" style="position: absolute; top: 10px; left: 42px;"></span>
        <span class="fa fa-bar-chart" style="position: absolute; top: 10px; left: 65px;"></span>
        <input id="Text1" class="col-md-8" type="text" placeholder="Send Message" style="padding: 30px; border: 1px solid #aaa />
    </div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Your use of inline styles means that you have to use `!important` to override the default state of `black`:

```css
span:hover {
  color: green !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="row">
        <span class="fa fa-envelope" style="position: absolute; top: 10px; left: -5px; color: black"></span>
        <span class="fa fa-file" style="position: absolute; top: 10px; left: 20px; color: black"></span>
        <span class="fa fa-calendar" style="position: absolute; top: 10px; left: 42px; color: black"></span>
        <span class="fa fa-bar-chart" style="position: absolute; top: 10px; left: 65px; color: black"></span>
        <input id="Text1" class="col-md-8" type="text" placeholder="Send Message" style="padding: 30px; border: 1px solid #aaa />
    </div>
```

A better solution might look something like this:

```css
.fa {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  color: black;
}
.fa:nth-child(1) {
  left: -5px;
}
.fa:nth-child(2) {
  left: 20px;
}
.fa:nth-child(3) {
  left: 42px;
}
.fa:nth-child(4) {
  left: 65px;
}
.fa:hover {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="row">
  <span class="fa fa-envelope"></span>
  <span class="fa fa-file"></span>
  <span class="fa fa-calendar"></span>
  <span class="fa fa-bar-chart"></span>
  <input id="Text1" class="col-md-8" type="text" placeholder="Send Message" style="padding: 30px; border: 1px solid #aaa" />
</div>
```